# how to fix this error while executing command ng build --prod in angular project?

Tags: asp.net, angular

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm5/ng2-material-dropdown.js
>   Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
>       at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
>       at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:77:21)
>       at visitNodes (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16144:30)
>       at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16370:24)
>       at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
>       at visitNode (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
>       at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16265:21)
>       at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
>       at visitNode (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
>       at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16322:24)
>       at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
>       at visitNode (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
>       at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16333:24)
>       at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
>       at visitNode (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
>       at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16229:21)
>       at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
>       at visitNodes (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16144:30)
>       at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16379:24)
>       at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
>       at visitNode (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
>       at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\arjunsinh\source\repos\Splitwise\Splitwise.Web\ClientApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16377:21)

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Splitwise.Web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Splitwise.Web:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.10",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "6.0.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^6.1.7",
    "primeng7": "^7.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

[Details about version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fYDm.png)

Comment: Could you edit your question by adding more detail like package.json file?

Comment: yap sure, i have edited and added package.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4-angular/issues/78

Looks like this guys solved it.

Comment: thank you for replying so quick, i have already gone through that solution, i have install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.20 and it solves that issue but new error comes up 

Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
.....

and solving this problem brings me back to same old problem